# Append Python lambda result to list

Tags: python

The following program should print **3** if **0** is given as argument but prints **6**.

Not sure if the problem lies in the *lambda function* or whether the *logic* is incorrect. **Is it the lambda function that is incorrect?** Thank you.

```
def get_list_sum(p, func_list=None):
    if func_list is None:
        func_list = []

    for i in range(3):
        func_list.append(lambda x: x + i)

    s = 0
    for func in func_list:
        s += func_list(p)

    return s
```

Comment: can you give some input and expected output pairs? I don't see anywhere that you're printing

Comment: I'm getting *"list object is not callable"*, not 6.

Comment: Probably meant `s += func(p)` in the example.

Comment: It looks reasonable of your output

Comment: By the time you call the functions, `i` is already 2, for all calls. If you want to current value of `i` you need to capture it with something like: `func_list.append(lambda x, i=i: x + i)` Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) is the canonical answer to this issue?